# Crash iOS application

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

My application crash sometimes but I can't reproduce this, and I don't know the reason of crash. Below a link for what I found in crash file (ips):
http://we.tl/SRb84J750O

And in logs I found that

```
SpringBoard[197] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Dec  6 15:56:16 DreamIt backboardd[55] <Warning>: |GAXGeneral|info| Did verify event: [Guided Access App Did go Invalid]. Outcome: [In Progress - Delayed].
Dec  6 15:56:16 DreamIt mediaserverd[190] <Notice>: '' com.parisinside(pid = 359) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Dec  6 15:56:16 DreamIt mediaserverd[190] <Notice>: '' com.parisinside(pid = 359) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Dec  6 15:56:17 DreamIt mediaserverd[190] <Notice>: 'FigPlayer - 389' (pid = 389) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Dec  6 15:56:17 DreamIt UserEventAgent[23] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Dec  6 15:56:17 DreamIt ReportCrash[968] <Warning>: saved type '298' report (1 of max 25) as /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/JetsamEvent-2015-12-06-155617.ips
Dec  6 15:56:17 DreamIt SpringBoard[197] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.parisinside[0xa877]' was killed by jetsam.
Dec  6 15:56:17 DreamIt UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 375564219023: id=com.parisinside pid=359, state=0
Dec  6 15:56:17 DreamIt SpringBoard[197] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Dec  6 15:56:17 DreamIt backboardd[55] <Warning>: |GAXGeneral|info| Did verify event: [Guided Access App Did go Invalid]. Outcome: [Success - Session App is Frontmost].
Dec  6 15:56:17 DreamIt searchd[969] <Alert>: (Error) IndexGeneral in si_playBackMobileRecords:2313: played back 1 records
Dec  6 15:56:18 DreamIt searchd[969] <Alert>: (Error) IndexGeneral in si_playBackMobileRecords:2313: played back 1 records
Dec  6 15:56:18 DreamIt searchd[969] <Alert>: (Error) IndexGeneral in si_playBackMobileRecords:2313: played back 2 records
Dec  6 15:56:18 DreamIt searchd[969] <Warning>: ====^^^^ DuetExpert missing data, count -> people:0 applicationDeepLinks:0 applications:8 requests:1 missingAllDataRequests:0
Dec  6 15:56:18 DreamIt SpringBoard[197] <Warning>: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f039b90 V:[UIView:0x15f029410]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x15f7ab4c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f6dbae0 V:[UIView:0x15e4abc40]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x15f029410 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15e3cae20 UIView:0x15e4abc40.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x15f7ab4c0.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f7387c0 V:[UIView:0x15e4abc40(119)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15e327a20 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x15f7ab4c0(117.5)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15f7387c0 V:[UIView:0x15e4abc40(119)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Dec  6 15:56:18 DreamIt tccd[192] <Notice>: Refusing client without bundle identifier (/usr/libexec/duetexpertd)
```

Comment: To read your link, I had to accept some usage conditions, what I won't. But your logs say (DreamIt ReportCrash[968] <Warning>: saved type '298' report (1 of max 25) as /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/JetsamEvent-2015-12-06-155617.ips) that there is a crash report. Just look it up or post it.

Comment: I post the file in dropbox.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27162260/crashFile/JetsamEvent-2015-12-06-155617.ips
Thanks